# Testing Mersenne prime with Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In Joseph Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*, the author shows that $p = 2^{257} - 1$ is prime implies that $10^{p+1} \text{ mod } p = 100 \text{ mod } p$ by Fermat's Little Theorem. The latter statement is supposed to be easily disproven "using multiple precision and a simple loop" on a computer.

I think I might be missing out on some basic number theory (or even numerical) tricks. Could anybody explain how to efficiently calculate $10^{p+1} \text{ mod } p$ on a computer?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can easily calculate $10^{p+1}\mod p$ given that $\gcd(10,p)=1$ using fermat's theorem or euler's generalization of fermat's theorem from that $$10^{\phi(p)} \equiv 1 (\mod p)$$ and $\phi(p)=p-1$ [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler's_theorem)

Comment: [Iterated Squaring](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Exponentiation_by_squaring#:~:text=Exponentiation%20by%20squaring%20is%20a,binary%20digits%20of%20the%20exponent.) is the usual method for computing large exponentiations $\pmod n$.

Comment: @LuckyChouhan Thanks for your reply! Maybe my wording isn't clear, but the primality of $p$ is not given in this problem. Indeed, Fermat's Little Theorem is used to give the necessary condition of $p$ is prime, which does not hold according to the book. My question is exactly how to disprove the condition on a computer, which is supposedly easy to do.

Comment: Should have said, iterated squaring works particularly well with Mersenne numbers, as the most readily computed exponents the method provides are those which are powers of $2$.  Your $M_{257}$ is only $78$ digits long so the computations are not bad.

Comment: @lulu Right. Iterated Squaring (or rather, just squaring $257$ times modulo $p$ in this case) is the way. It is simple and works amazingly fast. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to have helped.  Very useful technique.